# EC2 instance missing or got renamed?

Tags: amazon-ec2

One of our instances is missing. Or it could have been renamed by someone. I see a similar instance (not willing to turn it on as it might affect some other service). I want to know if there is a way to know if it was renamed? or when it was shut down? I have the instance IP (which was active before) and it's not assigned to anything right now. Any way to locate or find out what happened?

Comment: Do you have Cloudtrail activated?

Comment: no i have not :-( Is there no other way to find out?

Comment: If there is an Elastic IP which was assigned to the instance, then the instance behind the IP must have been terminated. A rename wouldn't break the attachment between Elastic IP and instance.
Without Cloudtrail you aren't able get any more information about the API calls anybody made in your account (afaik).

Comment: Can the AWS support find out what happened without CloudTrail? I could raise a ticket.

Comment: I don't know if they're able to get this information. But you could try it of course.